# What is the most simple and visually good way to imitate html elements selection like in winform designer?

Tags: javascript, html, selection

I doing kind of special purpose html editor.
I have an TreeView of html tags hierarchy on the page.
I want to make html elements selection when I change selected node in TreeView.
For example, if I selected div or table or button in TreeView, I want to make that element look like selected on the page shown right near TreeView.

How could I do that? Changing element **bgcolor** is kinda not good in rare cases, when element do not support it. Would be perfect to show bold rectangle around selected element, but I don't know how.

I know how to invoke JS from WebBrowser, I ask about JS solution. Some ideas for what function like that would do:

```
function SelectObject(element_id)
{

}
```

I want smething like that:
[image]

Comment: can you give sample html?

Comment: sample html of what? there will be any html, no matter what inside. matter that it has function SelectObject that must imitate selection of any element in body (table, div, button, textbox). You can think about this html page too. For example, function must imitate selection of the textarea where we type comment.

Comment: it is just hard to visualize what you are trying to achieve without some sort of sample markup. If you just want to change the background color of some elements as a user selects them thats not hard

Comment: Edited my question with example of Visual studio form designer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're happy with background color change, use it. For elements which does not "support" background change, use element-type-specific thing, which you can implement later.

Or, you should use an overlay. There's an article how to find out position of elements http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35737/Absolute-Position-of-a-DOM-Element

Comment: Kinda many JS things, but maybe it good enough to use. As about element specific selection, could I get element type just by it's ID? I am not JS programmer, so... I am C, C++, .net programmer.

Comment: And another thing: JavaScript is single-threaded, and it runs on the GUI thread of the browser. When JavaScript runs too long, your web browser became dead. The good part: you can change _any_time_ DOM elements. You can hide and show 9999 times the same element, it will not change, just after the JS ends. So x.select(all) then x.deselect(some) is totally legal. Don't worry about it.

Comment: ok, thank you. I think I will try first to display a table with dashed border over needed element. will see what happens.

Comment: Add comment here if you have problems.